# Magento - Put an image next to top category menu name

Tags: php, html, css, magento

I would like to put a small image icon next to my each category and sub category name (Not replace the category name with an image just put an image after the category name). I have already tried overriding app/core/code/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php

I changed _renderCategoryMenuItemHtml after which referncing category_id in styles.css I was about to add background image where the code was

```
 $htmlLi .= '>';
$html[] = $htmlLi;

$html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
$html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
$html[] = '</a>';
```

with

```
$htmlLi .= '>';
$html[] = $htmlLi;

$html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
$html[] = '<span class="category_'.$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId().'">'.$this->escapeHtml($category->getName()).'</span>';
$html[] = '</a>';
```

But dint work. I am sure many might have wanted to display a small thumbnail image just after the category name. But just don't know any easy or straight forward way to do it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use CSS background-image?

Load up the template/catalog/navigation/top.phtml and add in a new class or id for each level's < li > items, maybe something like:

```
class="nav-<?php echo $_category->getName() ?>"
```

Then add those classes to your CSS, ie:

```
.nav-shoes { background: url(images/nav-shoes.png) no-repeat; }
```

Or even better, build a sprite image with all the images you want to use:

```
[class^="nav-"] { background: url(images/sprite.png) no-repeat; }
.nav-shoes { background-position: 10px 10px; }
```

Then all you need to figure out for each image is the background position.

Answer (score 0):

Use this solution  for Magento -1.8.*

Go intp Model file. (/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Observer.php)

In Function Name: _addCategoriesToMenu

Update following code

```
  $categoryData = array( 
        'name' => $category->getName(),
        'id' => $nodeId,
        'url' => Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getCategoryUrl($category),
        'is_active' => $this->_isActiveMenuCategory($category),
        'thumbnail' => Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getThumbnail()

    );
```

Then go into Html folder. (app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php)

at line 128 in Function name: _getHtml

Update the following line of code

```
    if($childLevel < 1 ){
        $urls = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$child->getData('thumbnail');
        $img = '<img src="'.$urls.'" />';
    }

    $html .= '<li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
    $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
        . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . ' </span> '.$img.' </a>';
```